# SLOW SQL Query using Max and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, max, query-optimization

I have the following SQL query, but even with indexes in place, it's taking over 15 seconds to show the results. I have been testing alternative ways but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Is there an alternative way to do the following query?

- Factable has: 47,896,402 rows
- Query is supposed to return 360k rows

Code:

```
SELECT
    EID, MAX(PDate) AS PDate, 
    ActionUid, MessageID, MessageTypeID, 
    EUid, DID, CID, PTimeID 
FROM
    Q_Net_FactTable 
WHERE
    MID = 5 AND CID = 222 
    AND (PTimeID >= 1879 OR PTimeID >= 1934) 
GROUP BY
    EID, ActionUid, MessageID, MessageTypeID, EUid, DID, CID, PTimeID
```

Query plan shows Sort is highest around 64% - I am guessing it's either group by or the MAX

[Plan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tTA6.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any indexes set on `Q_Net_FactTable` table?

Comment: Also it does not have any sense to have `(PTimeID >= 1879 or PTimeID >= 1934)` condition. You can simplify it to `PTimeID >= 1879`.

Comment: `With indexes in place` ... what are the indices you have on this table?

Comment: Indexes are set on fact table, also have cols store index have tried forcing indexes to be used does not make much difference

Comment: Please show the DDL for the tables involved, and the index definition DDL as well - plus if possible post your execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: cant seem to get paste the plan to work just says: The supplied XML did not parse correctly. Are you sure you have a valid query plan XML text?

Comment: Can you put the XML into [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Nvr7FRX7

Comment: i found if i add option (recompile) on end it seems a lot quicker.. i guess cause we use aload of @prams

Comment: PasteThePlan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryrT7_AHc @Larnu for some reason PasteThePlan doesn't recognize `ShowPlanXML` nodes with newer `Version` attributes

Comment: Probably worth letting them know via a [bug report](https://www.brentozar.com/contact/) @Charlieface .

Comment: `PTimeID >= 1879 OR PTimeID >= 1934` is causing some issues, and doesn't seem to make sense anyway: could be simplified to just `PTimeID >= 1879`. Also you have a spill on the `Sort` so maybe try `OPTION (MIN_GRANT_PERCENT = 5)` or some other suitable percentage of server memory

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Answer (score 0):

So, aside from rewriting and putting the max(pDate) as the last column because all the other columns are to be the
UNIQUE group by, I would start by having a single index that contains

```
(MID, CID, PTimeID, PDate, EID, ActionUid )
```

That will help in your WHERE criteria AND the first 2 of your GROUP by.

```
SELECT
        EID, 
        ActionUid, 
        MessageID, 
        MessageTypeID, 
        EUid, 
        DID, 
        CID, 
        PTimeID,
        MAX(PDate) AS PDate
    FROM
        Q_Net_FactTable 
    WHERE
            MID = 5 
        AND CID = 222 
        AND PTimeID >= 1879 
    GROUP BY
        EID, 
        ActionUid, 
        MessageID, 
        MessageTypeID, 
        EUid, 
        DID, 
        CID, 
        PTimeID
```

Now, You also have other things in your group by, and I am wondering if they really are specifically required or not, not knowing your data.
Are any of these other values always the same?  For example, if you have an order table to order details, the order header would have the
same value for a customer, no matter how many line items were in a given order.  Again, not knowing your data, are there any similar?
Such as for a given EID, ActionUid, what is/are the parts after that.  If you can EDIT your post to clarify that might help eliminate
the need to "group" by all the columns that would never change by just changing them to a MAX( whatever_column ) since you know it will never
change.